# Good logging library for Lua

Tags: logging, lua, openwrt

I'm using Lua from [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) based Access Point device to develop some S/W on it.

I want to find a good logging libraries for Lua. Do you have any recommendation?
I checked about [lsyslog](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/lsyslog/lsyslog/lsyslog-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that lsyslog is good enough for OpenWRT.

http://luaforge.net/projects/lsyslog/

I can build it from OpenWRT by using the below feeds Makefile.

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=lsyslog
PKG_VERSION:=5
PKG_RELEASE:=1

PKG_SOURCE:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=http://files.luaforge.net/releases/lsyslog/lsyslog/lsyslog-$(PKG_VERSION)

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/lsyslog
  SUBMENU:=Lua
  SECTION:=lang
  CATEGORY:=Languages
  TITLE:=lsyslog
  URL:=http://luaforge.net/projects/lsyslog/
  DEPENDS:=+lua 
endef

define Package/lsyslog/description
  lsyslog is simple binding API from Lua to syslog.
endef

define Build/Configure
endef

define Build/Compile
        $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ \
                LIBDIR="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)" \
                CC="$(TARGET_CC) $(TARGET_CFLAGS) $(TARGET_CPPFLAGS) -std=gnu99 -fPIC" \
                LD="$(TARGET_CROSS)ld -shared" \
                so
endef


define Package/lsyslog/install
        $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/lib/lua
        $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/syslog.so $(1)/usr/lib/lua
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,lsyslog))
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [LuaLogging](http://neopallium.github.io/lualogging/)? see [Introduction](http://neopallium.github.io/lualogging/manual.html#introduction)

Answer (score 3):

A tiny little one: https://github.com/rxi/log.lua

Usage:

```
local log = require "log"
log.trace(...)
log.debug(...)
log.info(...)
log.warn(...)
log.error(...)
log.fatal(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

How fancy do you want the logging? Lua on Openwrt has the nixio library. It provides syslog access with openlog(), syslog(), closelog().
[nixio](http://neopallium.github.com/nixio/modules/nixio.html)

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, I know.

There is another way to skin the syslog: `luaposix`, package already in OpenWRT (at least 15.05.1). Using `luaposix`, your code could be as short as:

```
log = require("posix.syslog")
log.syslog(log.LOG_INFO, "Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

On OpenWRT, there is lua-posix library as a package. Then you could use posix.syslog http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.syslog.html.